# Show a part of next slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I want to show a part of next slide (10%), then when I move over that part of next slide it will show (30%).

Something like this: http://karimrashid.com/

Here's what I did till now:

```
<script>$.fn.cycle.defaults.autoSelector = '.slideshow';</script>

<h2>Show the left and the right slides</h2>
<div class="slideshow-container">
    <div class="slideshow responsive" 
        data-cycle-fx=carousel
        data-cycle-timeout=1000
        data-cycle-carousel-visible=1
        data-cycle-carousel-fluid=true
        >
        <img src="http://malsup.github.io/images/beach1.jpg">
        <img src="http://malsup.github.io/images/beach2.jpg">
        <img src="http://malsup.github.io/images/beach3.jpg">
        <img src="http://malsup.github.io/images/beach4.jpg">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS Code:

```
.slideshow-container {
    overflow: hidden !important;
    width: 50%;
}

.slideshow {
    overflow: visible !important;
    width: 90%;
    margin-right: 10%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CairoCoder/x89sQ/259/

Is there's any existing slider that can do the trick?

Answer (score 0):

why do you want to look some other slider. use what has used in that existing site.

http://karimrashid.com/js/script.js

Please let me know if you need further help.

Comment: It will take too much time to extract it, that's it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It's possible to implement the **half-cutted next slide** functionality in Elementor by utilizing the Swiper library.

```
setTimeout(()=>{
    var swiper = new Swiper('.testimonials_wrapper .swiper-container', {
      slidesPerView: 3.5,
      spaceBetween: 15,
      loop: true,
      navigation: {
        nextEl: '.testimonials_wrapper .elementor-swiper-button-next',
        prevEl: '.testimonials_wrapper .elementor-swiper-button-prev',
      },
      pagination: {
        el: '.testimonials_wrapper .swiper-pagination',
        clickable: true,
      },
    });
}, 2500)
```

Replace **testimonials_wrapper** class with your own section class.